# My function or button isn't working

Tags: javascript, function

Any help is appreciated and my code is posted below. 
I've read my course book, followed the instructions of my professor, gone on youtube, read forums and still don't know why my button is not running my function when I click it. Please help.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<h1>Exercise 3-1</h1>
<script src ="X_3_1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Enter First Name:
<input type="text" id="firstName">
<br>
 Do you have children?:
 <input type="text" id="children">
 <br>
  If so, how old is your oldest child?:
 <input type="text" id="oldestChild">
 <br>
 <input type="button" onclick="processInfo()" value="Submit Information">
 <br>
 <span id="mymsg">*</span>
 </p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

JS:

```
function processInfo()
{
var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
var children = document.getElementById("children").value;
var oldestChild = document.getElementById("oldestChild").value;
var childrenLower = children.toLowerCase();
var today = new Date ();

if(childrenLower == "yes" || childrenLower == "y")
{
if(isNaN(oldestChild)){
    mymsg.firstChild.nodeValue = oldestChild + " is not a number";
} else if(oldestChild <= 19){
    mymsg.firstChild.nodeValue = "You still have kids at home";
} else if(oldestChild >= 19){
    mymsg.firstChild.nodeValue = "Hopefully they have moved out of the
house";
} 
} else if(childrenLower != "yes" || childrenLower != "y") {
mymsg.firstChild.nodeValue = "It must be peacefule at home, " +
firstName + "on this date of " today;
}
}
```

Comment: Look at the JavaScript console...

Comment: @epascarello, console was dead because of line break. ;) That confused me, too.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was missing a + sign before the variable today on the last line. Thanks anyway.